# Serious anaconda error :failed with repodata from current_repodata.json

Tags: python, anaconda

I got fatal problem with using anaconda.
When I use conda update, conda install
Always arise failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

And It take several "HOUR" then fail to search packages.

Even I cannot do:

`conda update --all` OR `conda update -n base conda`

I don't know what happened my server.

Error example below:

```
(base) [hanjg@h5 ~]$ conda update conda -c conda-canary
```

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with
next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed

Solving environment: | failed

CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt(->It takes too much time so I interrupt)

My conda channel list: default (Last priority), conda-forge(Top priority), bioconda

other server computer works well(it is not problem with internet or network authorization.)

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and have been trying to fix for hours. Setting channel priority to false seems to be the thing that has worked best so far. In the end, to get things working I:

- Deleted all traces of conda and did fresh install
- Started with: `conda config --set channel_priority false`
- Then: `conda update conda`
- Followed by: `conda update --all --yes`
- Then started installing my usual packages etc.

Comment: What does it mean by "Deleted all traces of conda and did fresh install"?